# Make the right LINQ request

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have table in a database that stores the following objects:

```
public class MyObjInfoWebView
{
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Certificate { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
}
```

I also have a list of serial numbers, for example this:

`var list = new List<string> {"010719/522", "010719/523", "010719/524", "010719/525", "010719/526"}`

Is it possible to write (and how) LINQ query to filter objects from the table according to the available list of serial numbers and the required language?

Comment: What do you mean by "tables" (plural)? It looks like one table. Are you looking for `list.Contains(x => x.SerialNumber`) ?

Comment: @Crowcoder yes one table, I sealed up

Comment: @Crowcoder I need to select from the table all the elements that correspond to the elements of the list, as well as a specific language

Comment: Linq is not the same as Entity Framework but if you  have and EF model `webView` I think you are looking for `webView.Where(x => list.Contains(x.SerialNumber));`. I can't really be sure enough about your question to write an answer.

Comment: @Crowcoder: I think you are right. You need to add to the query language comparison to write an answer. Which might be something like `webView.Where(x => list.Contains(x.SerialNumber) && x.Language == language);`.

Comment: @dropoutcoder, I wrote so, but filtering takes place only by language. It does not filter by serial numbers.

Comment: @РоманТимохов: Can you check query generated by EF? In debug mode it should be written in Output window in VS.

Comment: @dropoutcoder, `_contex.InfoWeb.Where(x => list.Contains(x.SerialNumber) && x.Language == lang).ToListAsync();` In debug i get more than 1000 items

Comment: @dropoutcoder, I'm sorry, everything works. I did not change the repository method, oops.

Comment: @РоманТимохов: Good to hear!

Comment: @Crowcoder: Write your answer. It works ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This request solved my problem

```
_contex.InfoWeb.Where(x => list.Contains(x.SerialNumber) && x.Language == lang).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't need `await` at the beginning of that query? Looks like an asynchronous call.

Comment: This one is good, but the contains will not fetch perfect match. instead of that you can use .Equals(x.SerialNumber)